# PSAD Firewall/ UDP flood?

Tags: firewall, psad

Well I'm actually trying to block a UDP Flood on the Application port because the string "getstatus" is causing my application to make large output due to a small input to the attacker's IP.

I installed PSAD firewall to do the job.

psad -S shows 3000,000 logged packets at the application port and top ports in Scan but does not block the IP of the attacker however other IP Addresses with small number of connections are dropped. I'm thinking that since output is also being made to the attacker, this is why its not getting blocked because iptables rate-limiting is also exactly doing the same thing and not blocking the IP where outgoing connection is also made.

Any guesses why it won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the case here was that the rate was actually higher than 200/s so this is why the firewall wasn't working. This was because the packets were no longer new  (--state NEW ).